# How to deploy to sharepoint?

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, deployment

Been working some with SharePoint 2010 for a litle while and it feels like my deployment method is way to slow and way to complicated, so my question is basically..

Is there anyway for me to deploy a package to a remote sharepoint server directly from Visual studio?..

For instance.. could I some how create a connection between my visual studio project and the sharepoint server I want to deploy to and then simply press some kind of "Deploy-button" that then deploys the whole project(or even better just my changes) against the remote sharepoint-server?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your current way of deploying?

Comment: well..for now im just deploying .wsp:s and send them to the hosts-support which installs the packages on a pre-production sharepoint server.. but we need a more efficient way for testing the deploys.. since Im not developing for sharepoint on a daily basis.. its very in-efficient to have to host my own enviroment and trying to keep that one synced against the product enviroment.. but the host has no problem keeping a pre-production enviroment up to date with the production enviroment.. which then makes it perfect if I just sort of could "push" my deploys to the pre-production server

Comment: Instead of creating a "wsp" have you tried right clicking on the solution in Visual studio and -> "Deploy Solution"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't be easy. Firstly there is the `Deploy` option which you have for every SharePoint project. This deploys the Solution (WSP) to the URL you specified under `Site URL` for the project. However this won't help you in your case because it only deploys to a local SharePoint Server.

There simply is no automated way to deploy to a remote server from within Visual Studio. What you are talking about actually has aspects of *Continuous Integration* -> Continuously wanting to deploy on each check-in.
The perfect tool for continuous integration is the Team Foundation Server. There you will have the possibility to create a deployment script (via a  TFS workflow) which automatically increases the version number of your assemblies as well as deploys them to a remote SharePoint server. This usually is done via PowerShell remoting.

PowerShell is the keyword here as in the end you could create your own PowerShell deploy scripts and just call them in the Visual Studio Post-Build instead of using a full fledged TFS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :).. I will be looking into this

Comment: FYI, within vs2012, you can publish to remote server easily.

Comment: Remember that dependent on how big your package is, each time your press deploy could result in downtime for any Users on the site.